# 96 Toyota Previa starts with no wires connected to the distributor

Tags: engine, toyota, distributor, spark-plug-wires

I changed my distributor and rotor the wires werent on yet and my kid turned the key and the van started right up how is this possible?

Comment: Please send a video

Comment: Which wires?  The ones that go to the spark plugs?